# merging ruby hash with array of values into another hash with array of values

Tags: ruby, hash

I can't seem to find anywhere that talks about doing this.

Say I have a hash `{"23"=>[0,3]}` and I want to merge in this hash `{"23"=>[2,3]}` to result with this hash `{"23"=>[0,2,3]}`

Or how about `{"23"=>[3]}` merged with `{"23"=>0}` to get `{"23"=>[0,3]}`

Thanks!

Comment: Well, *what have you tried*? Anyway, looked at `inject`? There might be a more clever zip-by-key approach, though...

Comment: @pst: Or, better, `reduce`? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Or something :-)

Comment: I've looked at both inject and reduce but I honestly don't understand how those function work and what they are capable of doing. They have always been a mystery to me. :\

Comment: What do you mean you looked at both, they are aliased methods. I guess @SergioTulentsev was trying to make a joke. If you want to understand how they work, you should read up on folds: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Comment: @MichaelKohl: yes, exactly, that was supposed to be a joke :)

Comment: lol, exactly why I didn't catch the joke. Because I just don't understand those methods. Thanks Michael, I will read up on them on that wiki. See if I can understand better. :]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
{ "23" => [0,3] }.merge({ "23" => [2,3] }) do |key, oldval, newval| 
  oldval | newval
end
#=> {"23"=>[0, 3, 2]}
```

More generic way to handle non-array values:

```
{ "23" => [0,3] }.merge({ "23" => [2,3] }) do |key, oldval, newval|
  (newval.is_a?(Array) ? (oldval + newval) : (oldval << newval)).uniq
end
```

Updated with a Marc-André Lafortune's hint .

Comment: Didn't know merge could take a block. Sweet!

Comment: That is awesome. Works perfectly! +1 for megas! Thanks!

Comment: Better, shorter, faster to use `oldval | newval` then `(oldval + newval).uniq`

Comment: Awesome, thanks Marc-André Lafortune Faster and shorter is always better. :]

Comment: How to merge everything? I mean if there is `23 => [], 24 => []`, I want to merge all to one single array []