# Group array of hashes by count

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
[
  { id: 1, art: "art_123" },
  { id: 2, art: "art_234" },
  { id: 3, art: "art_123" }
]
```

I need to have the following output:

```
[
  { art: "art_123", ids: [1,3] }
  { art: "art_234", ids: [2] }
]
```

I've tried to group by "art" but I can't solve this.
How to count total entries from every art?

Comment: Other similar questions include: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538049/merge-an-array-of-hashes-by-key-value-pair https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171834/merging-ruby-hash-with-array-of-values-into-another-hash-with-array-of-values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233493/merge-duplicates-in-array-of-hashes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370852/how-to-merge-two-hashes-with-same-id-by-combining-keys-with-different-values

Comment: `arr.group_by {|c| c[:art]}.transform_values {|v| v.pluck(:id)}`

Answer (score 1):

The following is one way to obtain your desired result.

```
array = [{ id: 1, art: "art_123" },
         { id: 2, art: "art_234" },
         { id: 3, art: "art_123" }]
```

```
array.group_by { |hash| hash[:art] }
     .map do |k, v|
       { art: k, ids: v.map { |hash| hash[:id] } }
      end
  #=> [{ art: "art_123", ids: [1,3] },
  #    { art: "art_234", ids: [2] }]
```

Comment: Good answer. My main suggestion--a very minor one--is to make it more readable by  writing the code on multiple lines (to which you alluded). I generally don't like editing answers  but have done so here because I was unable to make my point clearly in a comment. Also I don't know why you said, "It is not pretty", as it's just fine, so I took that out. All that is purely a matter of style, however, so if you prefer to put your code on one line, or still think your code is ugly, by all means roll your answer back to what you had before or edit what I wrote.